# How to set the correct Samba chmod permissions for folders in ext4 file system? Is ext4 the right choice?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, file-permissions, active-directory

I am build another Samba server as an Active Directory Domain Controller to replace an old and buggy one.

Every night I rsync the old one with the new one.

Now I am only changing the shares names in smb.conf in the new server for testing but, even with **Administrator**, I have no permission to assign groups and users to the shares using Windows.
What I am doing wrong? I've tried using chmod 777, 0777 1777, 2777, 775, 755, 0755, 0775. Which permissions are the correct ones in this situation?

I am using a compiled version of samba, 4.1.16 today, in the new server. The smb.conf:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = NEWDOM
        realm = ad.newdom.lan
        netbios name = DOM2
        interfaces = lo eth0
        bind interfaces only = Yes
        server role = active directory domain controller
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/funarbe.org.br/scripts
        read only = no

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = no

[myshare1]
        path = /home/shares/share1
        read only = no

[theshare]
        path = /home/shares/share
        read only = no
```

[Edit]
I am starting to think that it has something to do with ext4.

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys from samba.org sometimes update/change samba's wiki. Few weeks earlier the added to the main wiki page, https://wiki.samba.org, two new entries: [Setup and configure file shares using POSIX ACLs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Shares_with_POSIX_ACLs) and [Setup and configure file shares using Windows ACLs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Shares_with_Windows_ACLs) (which where "hidden" inside the "more..." link with bit less text). Now using both methods (not yet fully tested in my config) are working.

So creating or modifying the shares permissons to 2770 and setting the permissions with setfacl -m g:"":rwx is working. Using the [Troubleshooting](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Shares_with_Windows_ACLs#Troubleshooting) to reset acls now makes sense:

```
# setfacl -b /path/to/share
# setfacl -b /path/to/share/*
# setfacl -R -m default:group:domain\ admins:rwx /path/to/share
```

It seems they are improving the documentation (wiki) (Good!!!!!)